# How to change Redmine to support versioned files in every issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

Its [redmine](http://redmine.org), a Ruby on Rails application. Currently, every issue can have one or more files. But if a user decide to update/change them, the old files are replaced. My task is to develop something to allow versioned files for every issue: so, if a user update the content of an existing issue, the previous state of the issue is preserved and it can be displayed in some form.

I'm new to RoR and Redmine development.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing in this case is to modify Redmine so that instead of uploading files to the issue, you put the files into a subversion repository and then add a link in the issue.

Alternatively, allow multiple files to be added, and modify to code to rename them everytime one is uploaded - appending a suffix (_1, _2 etc) to each filename.